# How to simplifiled the following tensorRT makefile? The makefile seems so complecated, how to simplify it so as to make it more readable?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

The makefile of the tensorRT 0.5.2 is as follows, how to simplify it or convert it to CMakeLists.txt？
Iam confused about the .d file or .o file, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
.SUFFIXES:
TRIPLE=x86_64-linux
CUDA_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/cuda
CUDNN_INSTALL_DIR=$(CUDA_INSTALL_DIR)

CUDNN_LIBDIR=lib64
CUDA_LIBDIR=lib64
CC = g++
CUCC =$(CUDA_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/nvcc -m64

AT=

ECHO = @echo

SHELL=/bin/sh

ROOT_PATH=./
OUT_PATH=$(ROOT_PATH)/bin
OUTDIR=$(OUT_PATH)


#$(call make-depend,source-file,object-file,depend-file)
define make-depend
  $(AT)$(CC) -MM -MF $3 -MP -MT $2 $(COMMON_FLAGS) $1
endef

#########################

INCPATHS    =-I"$(CUDA_INSTALL_DIR)/include" -I"/usr/local/include" -I"/usr/local/include/opencv" -I"../include" -I"../common" -I"$(CUDNN_INSTALL_DIR)/include" -I"../../include" $(TGT_INCLUDES)
LIBPATHS    =-L"$(CUDA_INSTALL_DIR)/targets/$(TRIPLE)/$(CUDA_LIBDIR)" -L"/usr/local/lib" -L"../lib" -L"$(CUDA_INSTALL_DIR)/$(CUDA_LIBDIR)" -L"$(CUDNN_INSTALL_DIR)/$(CUDNN_LIBDIR)" -L"../../lib" $(TGT_LIBS)


.SUFFIXES:
vpath %.h $(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES)
vpath %.cpp $(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES)

COMMON_FLAGS += -Wall -std=c++11 $(INCPATHS)
COMMON_FLAGS += -D_REENTRANT
COMMON_LD_FLAGS += $(LIBPATHS) -L$(OUTDIR)

OBJDIR    =$(OUTDIR)/chobj
DOBJDIR   =$(OUTDIR)/dchobj

COMMON_LIBS = -lcudnn -lcublas -lcudart_static -lnvToolsExt -lcudart -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core


COMMON_LIBS += -lrt -ldl -lpthread

LIBS  =-lnvinfer -lnvparsers -lnvinfer_plugin -lnvonnxparser $(COMMON_LIBS)
DLIBS =-lnvinfer -lnvparsers -lnvinfer_plugin -lnvonnxparser $(COMMON_LIBS)
OBJS   =$(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(wildcard *.cpp $(addsuffix /*.cpp, $(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES))))
DOBJS  =$(patsubst %.cpp, $(DOBJDIR)/%.o, $(wildcard *.cpp $(addsuffix  /*.cpp, $(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES))))
CUOBJS =$(patsubst %.cu, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(wildcard *.cu $(addsuffix  /*.cu, $(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES))))
CUDOBJS =$(patsubst %.cu, $(DOBJDIR)/%.o, $(wildcard *.cu $(addsuffix  /*.cu, $(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES))))

CFLAGS=$(COMMON_FLAGS)
CFLAGSD=$(COMMON_FLAGS) -g
LFLAGS=$(COMMON_LD_FLAGS)
LFLAGSD=$(COMMON_LD_FLAGS)

all: release
release : $(OUTDIR)/$(OUTNAME_RELEASE)

$(OUTDIR)/$(OUTNAME_RELEASE) : $(OBJS) $(CUOBJS)
    $(ECHO) Linking: $@
    $(AT)$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS) -Wl,--start-group $(LIBS) -Wl,--end-group
    # Copy every EXTRA_FILE of this sample to bin dir
    $(foreach EXTRA_FILE,$(EXTRA_FILES), cp -f $(EXTRA_FILE) $(OUTDIR)/$(EXTRA_FILE); )

$(OUTDIR)/$(OUTNAME_DEBUG) : $(DOBJS) $(CUDOBJS)
    $(ECHO) Linking: $@
    $(AT)$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGSD) -Wl,--start-group $(DLIBS) -Wl,--end-group

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(AT)if [ ! -d $(OBJDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(OBJDIR); fi
    $(foreach XDIR,$(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES), if [ ! -d $(OBJDIR)/$(XDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$(XDIR); fi;) :
    $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    $(ECHO) Compiling: $<
    $(AT)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(DOBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(AT)if [ ! -d $(DOBJDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(DOBJDIR); fi
    $(foreach XDIR,$(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES), if [ ! -d $(OBJDIR)/$(XDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(DOBJDIR)/$(XDIR); fi;) :
    $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    $(ECHO) Compiling: $<
    $(AT)$(CC) $(CFLAGSD) -c -o $@ $<

######################################################################### CU
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cu
    $(AT)if [ ! -d $(OBJDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(OBJDIR); fi
    $(foreach XDIR,$(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES), if [ ! -d $(OBJDIR)/$(XDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$(XDIR); fi;) :
    $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    $(ECHO) Compiling CUDA release: $<
    $(AT)$(CUCC) $(CUFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(DOBJDIR)/%.o: %.cu
    $(AT)if [ ! -d $(DOBJDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(DOBJDIR); fi
    $(foreach XDIR,$(EXTRA_DIRECTORIES), if [ ! -d $(DOBJDIR)/$(XDIR) ]; then mkdir -p $(DOBJDIR)/$(XDIR); fi;) :
    $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    $(ECHO) Compiling CUDA debug: $<
    $(AT)$(CUCC) $(CUFLAGSD) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(ECHO) Cleaning...
    $(AT)-rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(DOBJDIR) $(OUTDIR)/$(OUTNAME_RELEASE) $(OUTDIR)/$(OUTNAME_DEBUG)

ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
  -include $(OBJDIR)/*.d $(DOBJDIR)/*.d

ifeq ($(DO_CUDNN_CHECK), 1)
# To display newlines in the message.
define _cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0


endef
SHELL=/bin/bash
CUDNN_CHECK = $(shell echo -e '\#include <cudnn.h>\nint main(){ cudnnCreate(nullptr); return 0; }' | $(CC) -xc++ -o /dev/null $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) - $(COMMON_LIBS) 2> /dev/null && echo 'passed_cudnn_exists_check')
ifneq ($(CUDNN_CHECK), passed_cudnn_exists_check)
$(error $(_cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0)$(_cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0)This sample requires CUDNN, but it could not be found.$(_cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0)Please install CUDNN from https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn or specify CUDNN_INSTALL_DIR when compiling.$(_cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0)For example, `make CUDNN_INSTALL_DIR=/path/to/CUDNN/` where /path/to/CUDNN/ contains include/ and lib/ subdirectories.$(_cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0)$(_cudnn_missing_newline_5020fd0))
endif # ifneq ($(CUDNN_CHECK), passed_cudnn_exists_check)
endif # ifeq ($(DO_CUDNN_CHECK), 1)
endif # ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
```

How to understand the Makefile?
What does OBJ/ DOBJ mean? And why we have to compile cuda file separately? How to make the makefile more readable and easy to understand?

Comment: TensorRT v7.0 includes a `CMakeLists.txt` https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT

Comment: This isn't the kind of thing SO is appropriate for.  If you have a specific question please ask it.  Else, you can look at the documentation to understand what things are doing: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overview.html